# readyState is equal 4 but the responseXML is empty

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I’m using the « GET » method in a  synchronus way  but I have noticed that  the responseXML is empty even the readyState value is equal to 4 
Which means the response is delivered form the server side 
Anyone have an idea ? why the response is empty

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because target document returns nothing, maybe? Look !
[//sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/empty.php](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/empty.php)

Comment: no the data is ok I can see them in my log , seems to be a synchronus prob

Comment: "in my log" ? what does it mean ?

Comment: the target document returns the data as expected  but on the cleint side I can see them when calling in synchronus  way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the MIME-type of the result isn't

```
text/xml
```

or

```
application/xml
```

for some reason.

Comment: I used  ajaxObject.overrideMimeType('application/xml'); but same result . when calling with async=false i have no prob